# not able to read locked cell value with office js

Tags: .net, angular, office-js

We have created an Excel sheet and locked some cells in the sheet by using spreadsheet gear. We added an Excel add in to the Excel sheet once the Excel sheet was created. We are trying to read values by using office js.  Here is my issue: we are not able to read locked cell values with office js.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. It works for me after I've locked the cell and protected the worksheet.

```
async function getCell() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
    const range = sheet.getCell(1, 4);
    range.load("values");
    await context.sync();
    console.log(`The value of the cell in row 2 column 5 is "${range.values}"`);
  });
}
```